# Calling .bat file from c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Using this piece of code .exe running in server

```
string bat =null;
bat = "D:/folder/a.bat";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(bat);
```

> Error: Could not find the specified file.

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: have you checked the file exists on the server??

Comment: Have you tried using \\ istead of /

Comment: Also, not sure why you use `/` when backslashes are the common Windows directory delimiter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519328/executing-batch-file-in-c-sharp

Comment: You can condense the 1st 2 lines into `string bat = @"D:\folder\a.bat";`

Comment: Yeah tried \\ also... Getting same error.. when I tried the same code in desktop it is working. String path name are not taking in server it seems. Please give some suggestions

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266619/system-diagnostics-process-start-problem-can-not-find-specific-file

Comment: What context is the application running in, e.g. a Windows Service?  What account does it run under?

Comment: If it's ASP.NET then it's permission problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure the file really is located at that path.
2. Make sure your program has access to this path.
3. Use backslashes: `bat = @"D:\folder\a.bat";`

Answer (score 1):

Filepath in Windows doesn't take a forward slash, it's not a URL/URI.
Use backslashes.

Anyone of below should work if the program has access to the bat file.

```
string bat=@"D:\folder\a.bat";
```

or

```
string bat="D:\\folder\\a.bat";
```

Also, checking for the existence of the bat file will be a good practice here:

```
if(File.Exists(bat))
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(bat);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the slashes to backslashes:

```
bat = "D:\\folder\\a.bat";
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically you need to run an executable (like cmd.exe) and then pass it a parameter. cmd.exe specifically has two options /C (carries out the command specified by the string, then terminates) and /K (carries out the command specified by the string but remains open)

Comment: BTW, as others have noted, you would need to use backslashes on the parameter for the cmd prompt.

Comment: There is also another thread on the topic of running a bat file from a service here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361097/c-sharp-service-cannot-execute-batch-file

Answer (score 0):

Wrong path. Try

```
bat = @"D:\folder\a.bat";
```

Comment: that's the same path with the one in the question.